# this.getApplication()).getQuery() always returns null

Tags: java, android, searchview

Good afternoon people! I'm developing a search system in Android Studio, but I'm a beginner in Java language and probably my mistake is silly. I would like help to understand two things. First: Why can not I access `this.getApplication()).setQuery(query);` inside the `onQueryTextSubmit` and second. Why putting the `HomeActivity.this.getApplication()` it does not acknowledge error, but also does not access the value of the `query` in `loadFirstPage` that is in the end?

```
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setQuery(null);

// listening to search query text change
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    //                loadFirstPage(builder,query);
        ((MyApplication) HomeActivity.this.getApplication()).setQuery(query);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
//                loadFirstPage(builder,query);
        ((MyApplication) HomeActivity.this.getApplication()).setQuery(query);
        return false;
    }
});

String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getQuery();
loadFirstPage(builder,s);
return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `String s ` will be populate before those two methods execute. Those are methods trigger on events. Simply add a `System.out.println` method to see when the `onQueryText###` are executed.

Comment: This is indeed a silly mistake: listeners are signs of asynchronous programming model, which Android very much uses. When using asynchronous programming concepts, you can no longer read code from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should analyse your code flow. If your code starts, you set the listener (1. and 2. in the image), but they won't be called. (You only set them..)

After that, the `getQuery` will be executed, which returns `null`, because your `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange` were not called before the `getQuery`.

If your listener gets fired, then the query will be setted, but the execution of `getQuery` was done before.

[image]

If you want the query, you can add a button and execute the code of `getQuery` on button press. 
In your case I think the best way, is that you initialize `s` with a constant value for the first start.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! I learned a lot from everyone's answers, unfortunately I do not have a vote score, but thank you very much!